# gulp command showing error

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to run gulp command for the automation of my project but it ends up with an error. Below is my gulp file-

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webserver = require('gulp-webserver'),
    typescript = require('gulp-typescript'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

var appSrc = 'builds/development/',
    tsSrc = 'process/typescript/';

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src(appSrc + '**/*.html');
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src(appSrc + '**/*.css');
});

gulp.task('copylibs', function() {
  return gulp
    .src([
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(appSrc + 'js/lib/angular2'));
});

gulp.task('typescript', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(tsSrc + '**/*.ts')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(appSrc + 'js/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(tsSrc + '**/*.ts', ['typescript']);
  gulp.watch(appSrc + 'css/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch(appSrc + '**/*.html', ['html']);
});

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src(appSrc)
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      open: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['copylibs', 'typescript', 'watch', 'webserver']);
```

I have successfully installed all the dependencies with `npm install`. 
Here's what my package.json looks like-

```
{
  "name": "AngularJS2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Sky",
  "description": "Angular2 Newbee",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1"
  }
}
```

I am attaching the error below that I get on running gulp-

```
$ gulp
[10:44:11] Using gulpfile ~\desktop\angular2Ray\gulpfile.js
[10:44:11] Starting 'copylibs'...
[10:44:11] Starting 'typescript'...
[10:44:11] Starting 'watch'...
[10:44:11] Finished 'watch' after 31 ms
[10:44:11] Starting 'webserver'...
[10:44:11] Webserver started at http://localhost:8000
[10:44:11] Finished 'webserver' after 9.8 ms
internal/child_process.js:298
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:151:15)
    at exports.exec (child_process.js:111:18)
    at open (C:\Users\user\desktop\angular2Ray\node_modules\open\lib\open.js:58:                                                            10)
    at Server.openInBrowser (C:\Users\user\desktop\angular2Ray\node_modules\gulp                                                            -webserver\src\index.js:100:5)
    at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
```

Can anyone please help me with this situation. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find where you're spawning a child process in your Node app; that'd be my first suggestion for looking.

Comment: I didnt get you exactly?

Comment: One of your scripts seems to be spawning a child process. That's the module where the fault lies, but the console output and stack trace don't describe where. Alternatively, it could be one of the shims/polyfills that's overwriting the built-in Node `child_process`, causing it to fault.